# Html chart does not fit a small Android WebView

Tags: android, html, css, android-webview, chart.js

I have a WebView where Width and Height is 25dp. In this small WebView I want to show a circle digram from Chart.js, but it does not resize to fit the small WebView I have created.

the HTML for the circle chart:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="chart.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            html, body
        {
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="myChart" style="width:100%; height:80%;"></canvas>      

    <script>

        var chartData = [
  dataprotein,
  datafat,
  datacarb
];

        var data = {
        datasets: [{
                borderWidth: 0,
                data: chartData,
                    backgroundColor: [
                        '#FF604E',
                        '#4666FF',
                        '#47CC6F',
                    ]

            }],

        };

        var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
        var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
            // The type of chart we want to create
            type: 'pie',

            // The data for our dataset
            data: data
        });

    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Instead of reducing width and height use scale properties of css, to reduce size of chart.

Answer (score 1):

If the chart is the only thing you load up in webview. You can use `setLoadWithOverviewMode` when getting the settings for the webview to enable your webview to go into `Overview mode` which means the html content's width will be set to fit your screen. you can checkout the full detail [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html)

The code would be like this. 
(*Remember to set it before you load your HTML content into webview*)

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); //enable it since you're using js to create your chart
webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT); 
webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true); //incase you're using some DOM in your js
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true); //This code load your webview into overview mode, fit your html to the screen width
```

and afterwards, finally load your HTML to your webview

Answer (score -1):

```
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use this code to show a circle diagram from Chart.js

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url) {

        progDailog.show();
        view.loadUrl(url);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, final String url) {
        progDailog.dismiss();
    }
});

webView.loadUrl(url);
```